# How do I download an image from database using POST method

Tags: android

I have a requirement where a user image must be downloaded to the app from a database using the POST method. Here I need to pass `userId` through POST method to PHP and get an image as response. This image I will store and display it in an `ImageView`. I've already done this in iOS and its working fine there, but for Android I need help.

I have done plenty of Googling but only found tutorials to download image using GET method or direct URL method but no POST method. Please help me with any sample code using POST method.
PHP file i'm already using for ios is below.

```
<?php

require("userdao.php");
...
$userId = htmlentities($_POST["userId"]);

$returnValue = array();
$dao = new userdao($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$dao->openConnection();
$userPhoto = $dao->getUserPhoto($userId);
$returnValue = $userPhoto["user_photo"];
$dao->closeConnection();

echo ($returnValue);
return;
?>
```

Edit: Here is some additional info,
Images are stored in database using blob. The above php needs userid input & gets the corresponding image from table and then just echos it back. no json_encode here. I have other php's for this app that are doing string requests & getting responses back using volley & thats all fine. But for this particular one i need image as response, i am unable to find code for Image Request or Bitmap Request that could send one parameter using POST method & get image response.
This php is common for ios & android. I need code for android to make this work.
One more thing, after lot of search I have posted this question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. Download is not done by a POST method. Only the request for download is POSTED to the server. After that the file is just sent over the stream and hence received.

Comment: Just show the php code for a GET request. You will have to change very little to make it work with POST. You could also very easy make it so both GET and POST work.

Comment: Or does your php script work ok for POST and you are only asking for Android code? Unclear.

Comment: Hi greenapps, Yeah, my php is working fine for POST. i am using the same php for ios. I need android code to send userid using post & receive image in response.

Comment: i have seen plenty of blogs & posts on downloading image using direct url or GET method but not much info on POST method. I have already used this php for ios & there it is running fine. I need code for android. i post userid & i need to get image. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you storing only paths to the image location in your database? In that case, you could look into Volley library by Google and have an ImageLoader download your photo after the php service returns the image path to the app.To make the post request you would use a StringRequest if you aren't requesting anything else and maybe a JsonArray or JsonObject request if you are getting JSON

Comment: Code for uploading or downloading by post or get is posted every day onthis site. I you have the code fot get then it is so easy to adapt it for post. If you just read a couple of hours this site you will find enough code.

Comment: Hi iBobb, Images are stored in database using blob. The php i posted in question requests for userid & gets the corresponding image from table and then echos it back. I have other php's for this app that are doing string requests & getting responses back using volley & thats all fine. But for this particular one i need image as response, i am unable to find code for Image Request or Bitmap Request that could send one parameter using POST method & get image response.
one more thing. after lot of search I have posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it although not directly but with work around. I converted the image to base64 string in php. In android i used StringRequest to POST userid & receive encoded string, then decoded string & converted it back to image.

PHP code:
userPhoto.php

```
<?php

...
$userId = htmlentities($_POST["userId"]);
...
$userImage= $userPhoto["user_photo"];
$returnValue["userIdEncoded"] = base64_encode($userImage);
...

echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
?>
```

Android code:
Created new java file to get data from database:

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PhotoRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String photoRequestUrl = "http://.../php/userPhoto.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public PhotoRequest (String userId, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, photoRequestUrl, listener, errorListener);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("userId", userId);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Added following code to MainActivity for saving image:

```
Response.Listener<String> photoResponseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String imageResponse) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(imageResponse);

            final String userPhotoEncodedString = jsonResponse.getString("userIdEncoded");
            final byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(userPhotoEncodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            File imageDirectory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean isDirectoryExists = imageDirectory.exists();
            if (!isDirectoryExists) {
                isDirectoryExists = imageDirectory.mkdir();
                }
            System.out.println("isDirectoryExists:" + isDirectoryExists);

            File imagePath = new File(imageDirectory, "userPhoto.png");
            boolean isFileExists = imagePath.exists();
            if(isFileExists){
                isFileExists = imagePath.delete();
            }
            System.out.println(isFileExists);

            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                decodedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    };

    PhotoRequest photoRequest = new PhotoRequest(userId, photoResponseListener, null);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginPage.this);
    queue.add(photoRequest);
```

Following code to display image from saved file:

```
final ImageView ivUserPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivUserPhoto);

try {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File imageDirectory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File imagePath = new File(imageDirectory, "userPhoto.png");
    Bitmap userImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imagePath));
    ivUserPhoto.setImageBitmap(userImage);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```